# .net 3.5, does it need your computer to be restarted for it to work?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, restart

Hey gang, I need to know if i need to restart my computer to get .net 3.5 to work with my web applications after i install it.
My server machine is using IIS.
On my local machine the web app works fine.  When i browse to it on the server, i'm seeing errors like the Linq assemblies can't be found ... even though the references are in the web.config file and that for classes where i define properties using the snazzy no field generation way, the compiler complains saying i need to specify those very fields (again, this doesnt happen on the local machine when i build the web app).
Advice on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help (loading the latest version into IIS):

With a command window, get to the latest version of .net under
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\
Now run the following command: "net stop w3svc" to stop web services.
Then use "aspnet_regiis.exe -ua" to uninstall all instances of ASP.NET
from IIS.
Follow with "aspnet_regiis.exe -i" to install ASP.NET into IIS.
Now restart web services with "net start w3svc".

Comment: By the way.. If you're in .Net 3.5, the latest version of .Net would be v2.0.50727 which is the directory you want to navigate to in the command window.

Answer (score 0):

you may have forgotten to set the .net version for your site on your server to 3.5; i think it defaults to 1.1 or 2.0 if you don't reset it

(IIS maintenance utility can do this)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IIS7, then you do not need to run the aspnet_regiis utility.